# PingClass C# crashes my PC

Tags: c#, windows, crash, ping

I want to scan my network for users, but I dont know what happend... this code crashes my pc, can u help me pls?

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        IpAdressCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        var tmp = "192.168.1.";

        for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            PingAdress(tmp+i.ToString());

        }
    }

    private void PingAdress(string adress)
    {
        try
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = ping.Send(adress);

            if(reply != null)
            {
                IPStatus status = reply.Status;
                IpAdressCollection.Add(status.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

[BlueScreenView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8K9E.png)

Comment: Crashes how? What error or exception are you getting?

Comment: the complete pc crashes and gives me an bluescreen... details are in the picture

Comment: I suggest implementing the `using(var ping = new Ping()){ *** }` pattern, since Ping implements some form of Dispose().

Comment: A quick google on your error seems to suggests its memory related (bugCheck code 76).

Comment: Does it crash a machine if it is compiled and run as a console app?  Secondly, if you comment IpAdressCollection line and just console.WriteLine it, does it still crash?  Then all objects should have gone out of scope and disposed.  Failing that, run gc.collect() often-is - doesn't seem to be a huge production app anyway - so slower performance is fine.